# Why am I malformed literal error with pg-promise when SELECT has WHERE condition on a numrange?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying to select an item from a table where a given number fit's into its cost range.

It seems to work if I manually set `$/cost/` to a `3.136` but as soon as I try to use a named parameter it fails. I am using other variables int he full query and they all work fine, which leads me to believe I am doing something incorrectly as it pertains to [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/) and `numrange`

`db.one('SELECT id FROM cost_table WHERE range @> $/cost/', { cost })`

I get the error

```
Server running on port 5000
[0] { error: malformed range literal: "3.316"
[0]     at Connection.parseE (\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:602:11)
...
So on so forth
...
name: 'error',
[0]   length: 137,
[0]   severity: 'ERROR',
[0]   code: '22P02',
[0]   detail: 'Missing left parenthesis or bracket.',
[0]   hint: undefined,
[0]   position: '1896',
[0]   internalPosition: undefined,
[0]   internalQuery: undefined,
[0]   where: undefined,
[0]   schema: undefined,
[0]   table: undefined,
[0]   column: undefined,
[0]   dataType: undefined,
[0]   constraint: undefined,
[0]   file: 'rangetypes.c',
[0]   line: '2092',
```

Comment: You should log the outgoing query to see where the issue is. Use either [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) event or [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) for that ;)

Comment: Will give this a shot in the morning. Thank you!

Comment: Try `$/cost/::numeric`